# Why does my image download with Perl's LWP give me the wrong-sized file?

Tags: perl, image, lwp

I am trying to get an image from an HTTP server using Perl.

I have the full URL of the file and am attempting to use

```
my $data = LWP::Simple::get $params{URL};
my $filename = "image.jpg";
open (FH, ">$filename");
print FH $data;
close (FH);
```

Now, logically, to me at least, this should work.  But the files are slightly different sizes, and I can't work out why.

Help!

Comment: Is the only problem that the files are different sizes? How slight is slight? Is the image that is being sent to the user the same as the image on your server?

Comment: a 20k image was off by maybe 30 bytes.  Dave Hinton solved the problem.  I was not running in binmode.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use [`binmode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) to properly write the image data to disk.

```
my $data = LWP::Simple::get $params{URL};
my $filename = "image.jpg";
open (FH, ">$filename");
binmode (FH);
print FH $data;
close (FH);
```

Otherwise it is interpreted as text, and the newlines get munged.

Comment: You don't need a global filehandle hanging around like that. Use File::Slurp's write_file or LWP::Simple::getstore.

Answer (score 13):

Dave is right, you should/must set your file handle to binary mode. But you could do all that in one go:

```
LWP::Simple::getstore( $params{URL}, 'image.jpg' );
```