# How to display an image with Perl

Tags: image, perl

I want to write a perl script to auto login a website and do some interesting things. The problem is that the website which I want to log into has a captcha image. I don't have the ability to anticaptcha it, so I need to read the image then display the image to the user to let the user reads the characters on the image, then type the character in the command line back to the program. I want to know, what is the easiest way to display an image to the user?

Thanks.

Comment: this is for a terminal (i.e. text) application?

Comment: @JoelBerger he mentions `command line back to the program` so it is pretty evident it is a console application

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly you can use **[LWP::Simple](http://p3rl.org/LWP::Simple)** to [fetch the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926457/why-does-my-image-download-with-perls-lwp-give-me-the-wrong-sized-file) and save it to disk.

Afterwards , the simplest thing on **Windows** is to do

```
  system("C:\\imagepath\\foo.jpg");
```

which will show the image in the default application that is used to display it.

On **OS X** you can do

```
 system("open ~/imagepath/foo.jpg");
```

On **[freedesktop.org](http://enwp.org/XDG) standard compliant systems** you can do

```
 system("xdg-open ~/imagepath/foo.jpg");
```

These involve switching between a command line app and the OS designated application to view the image. If you want it more seamless you can use a [Perl GUI library](http://perl-begin.org/uses/GUI/) and create a window with downloaded image

Comment: `orz` Sorry for the botched edit, I did not notice that we overlapped in time.

Comment: Joel, I don't particularly care for such parochialisms. We have a [standard](http://portland.freedesktop.org) that universally applies to modern desktops building on X, mkay?

Answer (score 1):

Open in a web page?

Create your application as a web application an simply download the image with LWP then display it in your page (CGI  or Dancer, etc.)

You could put a simple text form that let you enter the code.